# Jquery slideDown messing up background gradient

Tags: jquery, css, gradient

So i have an annoying styling phenomenon happening with my gradient when combined with a jQuery slideDown function.

what i suspect is happening is that i have a global gradient that i have running on each page. on the one page i am using the following:

```
function slideOnlyOne(studiesName) {
 $('.studies_detail#' + studiesName + '_box').slideDown(200);
 $('.studies_detail:not(#' + studiesName + '_box)').slideUp(600);
};
```

so i am loading a few div's full of data and then just displaying one at a time using this jQuery function. here is a semi finished version of the site [here](http://mpowered.site44.com/studies/) so you can see what i am talking about. when swapping between white papers and infographics you will see that the background has weird effects like lines in the gradient as if its reloading it in some places somehow. but if you scroll to the bottom of the page and come back up again it resolves itself somehow.

has anyone else experienced something of this nature. and what should i do to fix it? change the jQuery?? the only thing i cant change is the gradient..

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(190, 190, 190));
background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(190, 190, 190));
background: -o-radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(190, 190, 190));
background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(190, 190, 190));
background: radial-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(190, 190, 190));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set

```
min-height: 200px;
height:auto;
```

Comment: thanks it bugs out a little on the first page but after that it works just great! you rock socks